# Infinite loop when try to redirect stdout

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt

I'm trying to send stdout to both console and `QTextBrowser` widget. But I'm getting some kind of infinite loop and then application exits.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

qtCreatorFile = "qt_ui.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(printing)

def printing():
    print("Pressed!\n")

class Logger(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.terminal = sys.stdout

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log_browser.setText(message) #problem is in this line

    def flush(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.stdout = Logger()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As a result, when click start_button, following is observed:

```
"C:\...\python.exe" "E:/.../qt_gui.py"
Pressed!
Pressed!
Pressed!
... (totaly 332 times)
Pressed!
Pressed!
Pressed!

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I just can't understand why this line makes loop:

```
self.log_browser.setText(message)
```

**Edit after 1st answer:**

I replaced the line above with `print(message)`, but still getting same results. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: There's an indentation error under the class defintion

Comment: It was copy/paste error, not from original code. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could emit a custom signal from `Logger` and connect it to the log browser:

```
class Logger(QObject):
    loggerMessage = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.terminal = sys.stdout

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.loggerMessage.emit(message)

    def flush(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sys.stdout = Logger()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.stdout.loggerMessage.connect(window.log_browser.insertPlainText)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I tried this code, but messages don't appear in QTextBrowser. Any suggestion why?

Comment: @dandepeched. It seems that `print` writes to `stdout` *twice* - once for the text, and once for the endline. So if you use `setText`, the second signal will overwrite the first. I've changed my example to use `insertPlainText`, so it appends all of the messages instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code you posted is not code you have run, but assuming it is representative, there are two errors: base class of Logger must be inited, and self.log_browser is not defined anywhere. But this does not cause loop, app exits (because there is an exception but no exception hook, see ). Since I don't know what log_browser should be, I defined it as a Mock() (from unittest.mock) which will accept anything done to it, and problem goes away.

```
class Logger(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        from unittest.mock import Mock
        self.log_browser = Mock()

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log_browser.setText(message) # problem was this line

    def flush(self):
        pass
```

Comment: log_browser is defined in the "qt_ui.ui" file, which translated by uic.

Comment: self.log_browser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)

Comment: I simplified code by replacing log_browser with print function, also initialized class as you said, but still get same behavior.

Comment: Calling print() from within the write() method will call write() again, leading to a recursion until Python interpreter runs out of stack space.